# Django admin, error deleting user

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to delete a user using Django Admin, but I get this error:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User found
```

What could cause this error?

The complete error:

```
TypeError at /admin/auth/user/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User found
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://www.domain.com/admin/auth/user/
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, User found
Exception Location: /home/user/webapps/django/lib/python2.5/django/utils/encoding.py in force_unicode, line 71
```

Comment: New news about this error:

i dont know what happen, but i can delete others user but not this one....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you trying to delete? Looks like you're passing it a User object, but it wants a string (probably the user name).

Comment: How? well, just selecting the user with the checkbox and selecting the action "Delete the selected user"... and too in the edit user form...

But how i can see that i can delete other user but not this one....mmm

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what happend, but I deleted the user from the database. I registered again (with the same username) and now all is fine. I deleted... mmm jejeej.